# hide footer if url is '/contact' and screen size is medium or large

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using AngularJS and Bootstrap.

I have a div with class footer as shown below:

```
<div class="footer">
    .....
</div>
```

**What I am trying to achieve?**

I want to hide this div on two conditions:

1. If url in browser is '/contact'
2. If screen size is medium or large.

If both of the above conditions are satisfied then only hide the div.

**What I know:**

1. I know how to detect url in AngularJS:
   I can use `$location.path`.
2. I also know that I can use media query to show or hide elements in css. Also there are classes like `visible-md` and `visible-lg` which can help me.

**What I don't know:**

Combination of both of the above conditions.

Comment: I don't know what you use as a templating system but you could use a different layout/partial for the contact page so that it has a special class you can control via mediaquery only. if this is not possible for you add a script that checks the url and add a special class to the footer if `location.href` ends with `/contact`

Comment: @fcalderan Can you please elaborate? I am using ejs as template engine.

Comment: If you know how to detect the url, could you not add a class to the body tag for that url and then you can just use the media queries to hide the footer if it is within that class

Comment: @Pete Yes, sure. I will try that.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in your js file

```
$scope.contactPath = false;
if($location.path === "contact")
{
    $scope.contactPath = true;
}
```

and put this code in your html file

```
<div data-ng-if="contactPath" class="footer visible-md visible-lg">
    .....
</div>
```

Now you can see only and only if contactPath is true and your screen size is medium or large.

Comment: I just changed a bit in your code. I think I should invoke $location.path(). So, I done that. And then I refreshed the page. But footer is always hidden. Then I changed ng-if to ng-hide, now if I am on contact page and then if I refresh the browser window, then footer is hidden. If I am on any other page and if I refresh the window, then I can see the footer. But footer only changes its visibility if I refresh the page. If I navigate through menu then there is no change in footer's visibility

Comment: @Vishal put this code in starting of each page (js file) to check whether the $location.path === "contact" or not.